# Elegant method to generate array of random dates within two dates

Tags: javascript, date, random, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker where I show two months and I want to randomly choose 3 dates in each visible month

```
  $('.date').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: processDates,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_icon.jpg",
    buttonImageOnly: true    
  });
```

Here is my calculation

```
var now = new Date();
var nowTime = parseInt(now.getTime()/1000);
var randomDateSet = {};

function getRandomSet(y,m) {
  var monthIndex = "m"+y+""+m; // m20121 for Jan
  if (randomDateSet[monthIndex]) return randomDateSet[monthIndex];
  // generate here
.
. - I need this part
.
  return randomDateSet[monthIndex];
}

function processDay(date) { // this is calculated for each day so we need a singleton for the array
  var dateTime = parseInt(date.getTime()/1000);
  if (dateTime <= (nowTime-86400)) {
    return [false]; // earlier than today
  }
  var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
  var randomDates = getRandomSet(y,m);

  for (i = 0; i < randomDates.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,randomDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
      return [true,"highlight","Some message"];
    }
  }
  return [true,"normal"]; // ordinary day
}
```

Answer (score 334, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but isn't this it?

```js
function randomDate(start, end) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

const d = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Perhaps - can you do that for 3 dates without overlap in each month?

Comment: By *overlaps* do you mean generating the same date? No, this code does **not** handle this case, theoretically it can generate the same date (especially when you truncate time). But it shouldn't be hard to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Related function for getting a date a number of days before (or after) the given date:

`function randomDateAfterDate(start, days) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + (Math.random()*days*24*60*60*1000));
    }`

Comment: to test @AutumnLeonard example for the case when we need the number of days before the given date we can use minus sign - randomDateAfterDate(new Date(2021, 4, 5), -365)

Answer (score 59):

```js
console.log(
  new Date(new Date() - Math.random()*(1e+12))
)
```

Comment: @Typescript users: `new Date(new Date().valueOf() - Math.random()*(1e+12))`

Answer (score 11):

> Using **Moment.js** && **@Demven Weir's** answer to get a string value like "03/02/1975".

```
moment(new Date(+(new Date()) - Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000)))
.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

**NOTE:** Keep adding a zero at a time to increase the span of years produced.

Comment: This adds nothing to the question. You're adding formatting that nobody asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```
function generateRandomDate() {
return new Date(+(new Date()) - Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000));
}

(new generateRandomDate()).toLocaleDateString('en-US')
```

You will get a random date in US format `4/25/2021`

See this Demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/husam_ebish/mvf2bdeg/2/)

Comment: This adds nothing to the question. You're adding formatting that nobody asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the boundary dates to integers (`Date.getTime()`) and then use `Math.random()` to generate your random dates within given boundaries. Then go back to `Date` objects with `Date.setTime()`.

Comment: x times without repeat (here x=3) ?

Comment: A matter of adding a loop and an array of already generated dates to check against when generating new one. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

From examples in [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/eachDayOfInterval)

```js
const result = eachDayOfInterval({
  start: new Date(2014, 9, 6),
  end: new Date(2014, 9, 10)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to get random date and format;

```
const emptyDate = new Date();
const randomDate = new Date();
const dateFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE');
const formattedRandomDate = dateFormatter.format(emptyDate.setDate(randomDate.getDate() - Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)));
```