# Why does the page not update after each button press

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, it should generate a random date every button pressed and update the text. however every time i press the button nothing happens(after the first press of course).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display what day it is today.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var d=new Date().getDay();
switch (d)
  {
  case 0:
    x="Today it's Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    x="Today it's Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    x="Today it's Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    x="Today it's Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    x="Today it's Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    x="Today it's Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    x="Today it's Saturday";
    break;
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvZSx/1/) for you to. This absolutly works for me in terms of the *current date*. If you wanted to have a random number you would have to generate such a number with this code

```
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

where `min` and `max` are the range you want to have, i.e. 0 to 6. I've added this to the jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

You are not generating a random date.  What the `Date` constructor does is return the **current** date. That's why, every time you press, the date remains unchanged.
If you want a random date, you could use this function which returns a random date between an interval :

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
}
```

and use change the line :

```
var d=new Date().getDay();
```

to

```
var d = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
```

***Note***:  the `random date` function is taken from : [Elegant method to generate array of random dates within two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035627/elegant-method-to-generate-array-of-random-dates-within-two-dates#answer-9035732)