# Why do this function doesn't return a random time that's > from now?

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to use following function (taken from an another answer) to get a random time that's > from now and within a hourly range.

I don't know exact value I need to put into `startHour`

My time is 4 PM EST US and I put 16 there and 5 to the `hourRange` but it gives me values that's less than that.

```js
function randomTime(rangeOfDays = 0, startHour, hourRange){
    var today = new Date(Date.now());
    return new Date(today.getYear()+1900,today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+Math.random() *rangeOfDays, Math.random()*hourRange + startHour, Math.random()*60)
}
```

Link to that answer, [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379536/14659574)

Comment: Think in ticks only. In other words just add ticks to the current ticks value.

Comment: @trincot Not mine. It's stated in the question that I've taken it from an another SO answer.

Comment: So why don't you just write code that you need? Maybe provide some concrete examples of input and expected output, and then we can maybe help you provide a function for it.

Comment: @Bibberty I have dyscalculia so unable to think in numbers

Comment: @trincot I have dyscalculia

Comment: Please at least link to the other answer, as required by the CC-by-SA-4.0 license...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Okay

Comment: Tricky, but I think its important to understand this type of exercise really requires `ticks` within a certain scale must be added.

Comment: Under the answer there is a comment, pointing out the mistake in this code: `this.getMonth()` should be `this.getMonth() + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this deals with the problem by working with Ticks only. Which is easier to manage.

```js
const getRandomTime = (offsetHour = 0, rangeInHours = 2) => {
  const curTicks = Date.now() + 0 * (offsetHour*60*60*1000);
  const addTicks = (Math.random()*rangeInHours)*60*60*1000;
  
  return new Date(curTicks + addTicks);

};

console.log((new Date()));
for(let i=0; i<10;i++) {
  console.log( getRandomTime(1, 2+i));
}
```

Comment: What exactly offsetHour do mean?

Comment: That allows you to say give me a random time starting at a minumum in X hours. e.g. `getRandomTime(24, 4)` will return a `Date` in a 4 hour range 24hrs from now.

Comment: Does it make sense.

Comment: I'm still puzzled of the 24 parameter and 4, feels like two ranges.

Comment: Give me some time to think.

Comment: Jeff, the first param just allows you to get a random time for a future date. Passing `0` is effectively a random time from `now()`

Comment: How to get a time within 9 and 5 range because yours gives me times around mid night.?

Comment: Actually,  I think your code has a bug. Even if I specify range of two hours, it gives me time values that exceed that limit such as mid night.