# A CouchDB view returning one element for each per "group"

Tags: couchdb

my database has plenty of documents looking like this:

```json
{
    "_id": "7fa2e319f3b908818d1c6eda9205fc6f",
    "_rev": "3-9db3d8cc45c9a45b35c3981011e77bb5",
    "Guid": "2d69ba2e-972e-4659-8d3f-35f660229b6d",
    "CompanyId": "foo",
    "Date": "2021-02-12T08:59:48Z",
    "Author": "Me",
    ...
}
```

The `CompanyId` key appears in all documents and several documents have the same `CompanyId` value.

I'm looking for a way to get the document with the most recent `Date` for each different `CompanyId` value. Said differently, I want an array of documents, each document with a different `CompanyId` value.

Here is a map/reduce pair:

```js
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.CompanyId, {doc: doc, date: Date.parse(doc.Date)});
}

function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var maxDate = 0;
  var maxDoc = '';

  for(i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i].date>maxDate) {
      maxDate=values[i].date;
      maxDoc=values[i].doc;
    }
  }
  return {date: maxDate}
}
```

If I pass `group=true` to my query, the map/reduce pair above successfully returns the dates of the most recent documents by company id:

```json
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "key": "a-testagency-556049-0897",
      "value": {
        "date": 1613123486000
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "a-testagency-556677-1317",
      "value": {
        "date": 1613123435000
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want more than just the dates in the result, I want the documents themselves so I change the last line to:

```js
return {date: maxDate, doc: maxDoc}
```

This unfortunately throws errors such as:

> "Reduce output must shrink more rapidly: input size: 37325 output size: 37233"

Is it because some company ids have just one matching document?

If I change the return line again to something smaller:

```js
return {date: maxDate, companyId: maxDoc.Author}
```

Then the query now returns `null` as value instead of the date and the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet at the end uses pouchDB to demonstrate one way (among a few) to achieve the desired result. This is a very simple solution, but the result is gained from 2 requests rather than 1 request.

To understand how this works check out the [Reduce/Rereduce](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html#reduce-rereduce) in the CouchDB documentation, particularly regarding `rereduce`.  An in depth write up here would just be a rehash of that documentation.

Here's the design document in the demo snippet.

```
{
    "_id": "_design/SO-66173759",
    "views": {
      "most_recent": {
        "map": `function (doc) {             
           if(doc.CompanyId && doc.Date) {                         
              emit([doc.CompanyId,doc.Date],doc._id);
           }
        }`,
        "reduce": `function(keys,values,rereduce) {               
           return values[0];
        }`
      }
    }
  }
```

The emit produces the complex key [companyId, Date], value = document _id.  For example:

```
[Acme Amalgamated,2012-07-26T18:57:12.409Z]   7fb19b37-5baa-4c78-b122-fd0bc67253d0
[Acme Amalgamated,2013-08-16T02:53:12.062Z]   93d480a5-a666-4fca-b4a4-c1ba7935de92
[Acme Amalgamated,2013-08-23T22:12:14.401Z]   96a236b1-50d6-4b7e-af45-d05432ca7847
[Acme Amalgamated,2015-05-20T13:17:21.500Z]   ad55f6e7-6c61-4793-a75c-9601debd5eaf
[Acme Amalgamated,2015-12-17T09:18:33.741Z]   cf1a0844-aa54-42e2-a9d6-16e80f5c420a
[Acme Amalgamated,2016-08-24T04:01:15.551Z]   0658a417-901f-4cc7-a005-c10c72d2720c
[Acme Amalgamated,2020-06-19T07:58:44.680Z]   56126238-496a-475e-9001-8a4a86e055a3 **
[Cyberdyne Systems,2012-02-02T17:07:30.692Z]    d8a2b649-10b0-467b-b7e1-304b13f7560a
[Cyberdyne Systems,2012-05-31T17:47:15.607Z]    64699ddb-e8f5-449f-b1cb-804ccddbbfb2
[Cyberdyne Systems,2012-07-11T13:08:00.879Z]    1aa285f4-dc4b-49e4-9f0b-331b3d552dad
[Cyberdyne Systems,2014-08-12T22:43:47.651Z]    f5597fb0-e37e-4a62-8ef2-244140b0439b
[Cyberdyne Systems,2015-03-25T04:54:40.459Z]    c80f58d3-9fb1-466f-9fd2-2b3f86331fc3
[Cyberdyne Systems,2017-08-13T02:42:49.530Z]    c2b2d636-b444-4216-9b0b-e982ea467e51 **
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2010-01-26T21:31:34.752Z]   d6e2b66d-286f-48b9-b678-7afeca2c3c01
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2012-07-04T02:29:20.509Z]   c7d528fe-ce4f-4c35-a054-39f726962b4a
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2012-10-26T01:21:11.765Z]   773af027-1fdd-4f41-b1b1-8d5169871684
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2012-12-15T22:27:12.999Z]   78d60df3-aed6-4cab-8071-4d08ccfd0184
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2014-11-04T02:03:49.328Z]   098f600c-8059-44d5-a526-b67f0bbeb609
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2017-04-30T14:54:17.967Z]   639ddd9c-9a41-42fd-b1be-7fea8eb4f3ec
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.,2017-11-21T10:45:53.152Z]   ee2a7445-276d-4e9c-9f9d-1fa76d87741f **
```

<sup>** Most recent document in companyId group</sup>

*Generally, emit'ing the document._id is redundant since view queries return the document _id - but there's a good reason to do so in this case which will be apparent later.*

Pay close attention how the index is ordered; within each company group, the most recent date is the *last* entry of a companyId group.

Now the terse reduce function

```
function(keys,values,rereduce) { return values[0]; }
```

will produce a pleasant result with the following parameters

```
{
   reduce: true,
   group_level: 1,
   descending: true
}
```

The `descending` property is the killer here because the `reduce` function will receive keys and values in *reverse order*; by returning the 0th value element, `reduce` will always produce the most recent document id according to the Date field, even when `rereduce = true`.

Given the prior example view, accessing the view with the above parameters would return the following key/value rows

```
[Lorem Ipsum Inc.]    ee2a7445-276d-4e9c-9f9d-1fa76d87741f    
[Cyberdyne Systems]   c2b2d636-b444-4216-9b0b-e982ea467e51
[Acme Amalgamated]    56126238-496a-475e-9001-8a4a86e055a3
```

and there it is - calling `_all_docs` with the values (document ids) with the following parameters

```
{
  include_docs: true,
  keys: [
   "ee2a7445-276d-4e9c-9f9d-1fa76d87741f",
   "c2b2d636-b444-4216-9b0b-e982ea467e51",
   "56126238-496a-475e-9001-8a4a86e055a3"
  ]
}
```

would return the most recently dated documents, distinct by companyId.

Here's a demo snippet.  The code generates 20 random documents and produces condensed view data.

**Important**
Do understand that the entire index is scanned for an unconstrained reduce.  If your index contains millions of documents then a more complicated approach may be in order, for example leveraging start/end keys or something interesting involving the [_changes](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/changes.html#db-changes) feed. YMMV.

```js
async function view_reduce() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-66173759/most_recent', {
    reduce: true,
    group_level: 1,
    descending: true
  });
  // show  
  gel('view_reduce').innerText = result.rows.map(row => `${row.key}\t${row.value}`).join('\n');

  return result;
}

async function showMostRecentDocs() {
  // Use results from reduce to get documents
  let result = await view_reduce();
  // The result row values are document ids; use allDocs to fetch the docs 
  result = await db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    keys: result.rows.map(row => row.value)
  });
  //show  
  gel('view_most_recent').innerText = result.rows.map(row => [row.doc.CompanyId, row.doc.Date, row.doc.Author].join('\t')).join('\n');
}

async function showViewKeyValues() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-66173759/most_recent', {
    reduce: false,
    include_docs: false
  });
  //show  
  gel('view_key_value').innerText =
    result.rows.map(row => `[${row.key}]\t${row.value}`).join('\n');
}

async function showViewDocs() {
  let result = await db.query('SO-66173759/most_recent', {
    reduce: false,
    include_docs: true
  });
  //show  
  gel('view_docs').innerText = result.rows.map(row => [row.doc.CompanyId, row.doc.Date, row.doc.Author].join('\t')).join('\n');
}

function getDocsToInstall(count) {
  const sourceDocs = [{
      "CompanyId": "Acme Amalgamated",
      "Author": "Wile E. Coyote",
    },
    {
      "CompanyId": "Acme Amalgamated",
      "Author": "Road R. Unner",
    },
    {
      "CompanyId": "Lorem Ipsum Inc.",
      "Author": "Caesar Augustus",
    },
    {
      "CompanyId": "Lorem Ipsum Inc.",
      "Author": "Marcus Aurelius",
    },
    {
      "CompanyId": "Cyberdyne Systems",
      "Author": "Miles Dyson",
    }
  ];
  // design document
  const ddoc = {
    "_id": "_design/SO-66173759",
    "views": {
      "most_recent": {
        "map": `function (doc) {             
           if(doc.CompanyId && doc.Date) {                         
              emit([doc.CompanyId,doc.Date],doc._id);
           }
        }`,
        "reduce": `function(keys,values,rereduce) {               
           return values[0];
        }`
      }
    }
  };

  // create a set of random documents.
  let docs = new Array(count);
  const dateSeed = [new Date(2010, 0, 1), new Date(), 0, 24];
  while (count--) {
    let doc = Object.assign({}, sourceDocs[Math.random() * sourceDocs.length | 0]);
    doc.Date = randomDate(...dateSeed).toISOString();
    docs[count] = doc;
  }
  docs.push(ddoc);
  return docs;
}

const db = new PouchDB('SO-66173759', {
  adapter: 'memory'
});
// install docs and show view in various forms.
(async() => {
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall(20));
  await showViewDocs();
  await showViewKeyValues();
  return showMostRecentDocs();
})();

const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);

/*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378526/generate-random-date-between-two-dates-and-times-in-javascript/31379050#31379050
*/
function randomDate(start, end, startHour, endHour) {
  var date = new Date(+start + Math.random() * (end - start));
  var hour = startHour + Math.random() * (endHour - startHour) | 0;
  date.setHours(hour);
  return date;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<div>View: distinct, most recent</div>
<pre id='view_most_recent'></pre>
<hr/>
<div>View: reduce result</div>
<pre id='view_reduce'></pre>
<hr/>
<div>View: key/value</div>
<pre id='view_key_value'></pre>
<hr/>
<div>View: docs</div>
<pre id='view_docs'></pre>
```

**FWIW**
Don't store documents as values! It is extremely inefficient.  Although a good reason may exist somewhere in the universe, I've never encountered a legitimate reason to do so.

Comment: Great! Happy to help.