# Select random date- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$("#text").each(function randomDate(start, end) {{
    var date = new Date(+start + Math.random() * (end - start));
    return date;
}

    var date1 = new Date(2000,09,01);
    var date2 = new Date();
    //alert($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy",randomDate(date1, date2)));
});
```

I want to be able to randomly select a date and put it in a textbox using javascript or jquery. The $("text") is the id of the text box.

Basically I want a simple solution to select a random date that automatically gets entered in the date textbox. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please copy+paste your actual code in the question so that we can work with it. An image actually makes it harder for people to help you

Comment: Also note that to select an element by its `id` you need a `#` in the selector, eg `$('#test')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant method to generate array of random dates within two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035627/elegant-method-to-generate-array-of-random-dates-within-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you out. check it

```js
function randomDate(start, end) {
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June",
  "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
  var date = new Date(new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())));
  var date = new Date(date);
  return date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date.getMonth() + 1)] + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
}

$("#text").val(randomDate(new Date(2004, 0, 9), new Date()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "text"/>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you. How do I get it in dd-month_name-yyyy format though? Example: 02-Jan-2017

Comment: I have slightly updated your code:

var datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate
(randomDate(new Date(0000, 00, 00), new Date()));
$("#text").val(datewithformate) ;

var datewithformate1 = DateAndTimeFormate
(randomDate(new Date(0000, 00, 00), new Date()));
$("#text2").val(datewithformate1)

I want (datewithformat1) to always be >= (datewithformat). The do while loop isin't helping. How can I achieve the above mentioned condition?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bharat Patidar will not sync with the jquery datepicker. You can dynamically update the datepicker with random date like below.

Create a separate function

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Update the datepicker object

```
$( "#text" ).datepicker( "setDate", randomDate(new Date(2004, 0, 9), new Date()));
```