# Unable to generate "Random Date value" using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Is there any way to generate "Random date value" to test a "date picker" in the "angualr 4 web application" using "Protractor".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant method to generate array of random dates within two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035627/elegant-method-to-generate-array-of-random-dates-within-two-dates)

Comment: Protractor is just a node app.  There are plenty of ways to generate random dates in node/javascript, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035627/elegant-method-to-generate-array-of-random-dates-within-two-dates)

Comment: +1 for the point that protractor is an NodeJs/ JavaScript app.I see lot of places people label plain JavaScript/NodeJs problems as Protractor issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own function which will return random date.

```
 findRandomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
    }

    this.findRandomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
```